# How to Serialize a JSON Parameter list of varied type and without names

Tags: .net, json, datacontractjsonserializer

I need to post a request to a server containing the following JSON. I want to use DataContractJsonSerializer and DataContract, DataMember attributes on the classes representing a request such as

```
{"method":"mymethod","parameters":[10,"somestring"]}
```

This represents an RPC call

```
mymethod(10,"somestring").
```

in some API. There are many calls with different parameter lists in the API.

This is straightforward if the parameter list contains objects of type T where I can use generic `List<T>` , but the API needs a list of parameters of different types (including non-primitive objects).

So how can I construct the DataContract for the parameters array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Lucas. So slightly restating the question to include complex types:-

{"method":"mymethod","parameters":[10,"somestring",{SomeProperty:value}]}

This represents a call to JSON RPC call 
mymethod(int,string,ComplexProperty)

```
The code is:-

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JSONConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        [DataContract]
        public class ComplexType
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class GenericRequest
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string method { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public object[] parameters { get; set; }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = 
                new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings() { EmitTypeInformation=EmitTypeInformation.Never, 
                                                           KnownTypes=new Type[] { typeof(ComplexType) } };
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GenericRequest),settings);
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, 
                new GenericRequest() { method = "mymethod", 
                                       parameters = new object[] { 10, "somestring", new ComplexType() { SomeProperty="value"}} });
            ms.Position = 0;
            string v = new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do all parameters string type - there will be serialized values of parameters.
Then you need to do like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;    
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string methodName = "test";
        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(ClassWithMethods).GetMethod(methodName);
        string[] parameters = new string[] { "1", "\"qwe\"", "{\"SomeProperty\":\"prop\"}" };
        object[] parameterValues = new object[parameters.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer s = new DataContractJsonSerializer(methodInfo.GetParameters()[i].ParameterType);
            object p = s.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters[i])));
            parameterValues[i] = p;
        }
        methodInfo.Invoke(new ClassWithMethods(), parameterValues);
    }
}

public class ClassWithMethods
{
    public void test(int i, string s, ComplexType ct)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", i, s, ct.SomeProperty);
    }
}


public class ComplexType
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is de-serializing a response, which might be helpful. I need to serialize the parameters.

Comment: `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
   DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(object[]), new Type[]{ typeof(ComplexType)});
   serializer.WriteObject(ms, new object[]{1, "123", new ComplexType(){SomeProperty = "456"}});
   ms.Position = 0;
   string v = new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd();`

Comment: Also you can use Json.net. It's simple and result would be more beautiful. `string res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new object[] {1, "123", new ComplexType() {SomeProperty = "456"}});` Result: [1,"123",{"SomeProperty":"456"}]